# @ExistQuery in Spring data mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

Hello I would like to do exist query in spring mongo repository. I read about @ExistQuery but I don't know how write query inside, my method now:

```java
    @ExistsQuery("{ 'userAccount.socialTokenId': ?1}")
    boolean existBySocialAccountId(String socialAccountId);
```

But I getting IndexOutOfBoundsException, 'userAccount' is a List of objects which contain variable socialTokenId. I know that I can just get whole User object and find it by myself but I would like to optimize my queries :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your problem is that the paramaters are zero indexed, so there is no parameter with index of `1`, which is causing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Try changing your code to the following:

```
@ExistsQuery("{ 'userAccount.socialTokenId': ?0}")
boolean existBySocialAccountId(String socialAccountId);
```